# Parsing HTML div tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I tried to obtain text from those div tags but they all return nothing:

HTML :

```
<div id="comments" class="part comments last"><script type="text/rocketscript" data-    rocketsrc="http://sabq.org/js/parts/comments/global.js?1324675506" data-      rocketoptimized="true"></script>
<h2 class="header">التعليقات (23)</h2>

<div id="comment_5946146" class="item
                                            ">
<h4 class="direction1">
<span class="serial">1</span> *محمد * </h4>
<p class="direction1"><span class="date-time">17 جمادى الأولى 1435 | 12:46 AM</span></p>
<p class="like-buttons">
<span class="like " title="أعجبني"><span class="value">5</span></span>
<span class="sep">-</span>
<span class="unlike " title="لم يعجبني"><span class="value">0</span></span>
<input type="hidden" name="class" value="Comment">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5946146">
</p>
<br clear="all">
<div class="message">هؤلاء أشخاص لم يجدوا سبيلاً لطلب الرزق إلا بهذه الطريقة فكفاكم تضييقاً وخناقاً عليهم حتى في مصادر رزقهم ....</div>

</div>
```

I wanna get the div class "message" and the text inside h4 tag and span "date-time"
I tried to:

```
document.select("div.message");
```

And:

```
document.select("div.comments").select("div.message");
```

But they didn't work.

Comment: Both code examples work fine for me. Can you post how you are creating document and how you are using these selects?

Comment: @Pshemo can you do it using this url http://sabq.org/WzUfde see if it works because I deleted some div tags from the html example that I posted

Comment: Yes. I had Error 403 which means that resource was forbidden but after adding user agent header same as my browser uses I could see it and parse without problem. Can you describe how exactly your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried against your html with 5 cases and they all work fine, just a little note - you are retrieving a collection of `Elements` and not just a single `Element` by using `document.select("div.message");`

Code:

```
 Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("some.html"),"utf-8");
    Element message = document.select("div.message").first();
    Element span = document.select("span.date-time").first();
    Element comments = document.select("div.comments").first();
    Element h4 = document.select("h4.direction1").first();
    Element test = document.select("div.comments").select("div.message")
                    .first();

    System.out.println(message.text());
    System.out.println(span.text());
    System.out.println(comments.text());
    System.out.println(h4.text());
    System.out.println(test.text());
```

Gives;

```
م حتى في مصادر رزقهم ....
17 جمادى الأولى 1435 | 12:46 AM
التعليقات (23) 1 *محمد * 17 جمادى الأولى 1435 | 12:46 AM 5 - 0 هؤلاء أشخاص لم يجدوا سبيلاً لطلب الرزق إلا بهذه الطريقة فكفاكم تضييقاً وخناقاً عليهم حتى في مصادر رزقهم ....
1 *محمد *
هؤلاء أشخاص لم يجدوا سبيلاً لطلب الرزق إلا بهذه الطريقة فكفاكم تضييقاً وخناقاً عليهم حتى في مصادر رزقهم ....
```

PS: I have used `.first()` to prove the validity of the used selectors, since your html had unique non-repetitive combinations. In case you have multiple results per selector, you can iterate over the collection and get the individual results, like:

```
Elements message = document.select("div.message");

for (Element el : message) 
    System.out.println(el.text());
```

**EDIT:**

To parse from the url:

Change,

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("some.html"),"utf-8");
```

To,

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://sabq.org/WzUfde").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21").get();
```

This works for me, cannot post the huge output here but you can test it for your case.

Comment: I'm actually parsing from this url http://sabq.org/WzUfde could you please try getting from it

Comment: @user2989698 Yes, I tried with the url and it works, cannot post the results as it is huge nonetheless edited the post above with the change for you to test it yourself. Just refer to the edit above.